# Specify path to sister directory in a style file

Tags: packages, paths

I'm about to share my LaTeX document and all its accessory files in such a way that it is self-contained and ready to compile. But I can't figure out how to refer to a sister folder from a `.sty` file.

I have the following `.tex` file in the mother directory:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{./testfolder/testpackage}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

And a `.sty` file called `testpackage.sty` in a daughter folder:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{./testfolder/testpackage}
\usepackage{libertine}
\endinput
```

So far, so good. But now I need to load another package from `testpackage.sty`, and the package I need to load is located in the sister folder relative to the folder `testpackage.sty` is in. So I try this:

`.tex` file in the mother directory:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{./testfolder/testpackage}
\begin{document}
Test
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

`.sty` file in daughter directory 1:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{./testfolder/testpackage}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{../testfolder2/testpackage2}
\endinput
```

`.sty` file in daughter directory 2 (sister directory of directory 1):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{../testfolder2/testpackage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\endinput
```

Trying to compile my `.tex` file results in this error:

> LaTeX Error: File `../testfolder2/testpackage2.sty' not found.

What am I doing wrong? According to [LaTeX/Modular Documents](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents), it should be possible to use `../` to specify sister directories.

(I know there are conventions for how to illustrate directory paths, but I couldn't find anything by googling, so I gave that up for this question).

Comment: You must give the path relativ to your main tex-file, not relative to the style, so probably you need `\usepackage{testfolder2/testpackage2}`

Comment: Don't do `\usepackage{./testfolder/testpackage}` it's a syntax error that will generate a warning if `\ProvidesPackage` is used in the package (as it should be) the argument to `\usepackage` is a _name_ not a file path (even though the latter sort of half works) the relative paths are always relative to the main input document not to the file with the \input

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't understand your comment, but I think we've been over this before [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111629/9077). I don't get any warnings.

Comment: @Sverre I noticed afterwards you'd put the same path in the provides package which suppresses the warning, but it's still wrong:-) it should be `\usepackage{testpackage2}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please clarify. ``usepackage`` + ``testpacakge2`` is used twice. Which is supposed to be replaced by ``\usepackage{testpackage2}``?

Comment: Is this really the best way?  Why not use `bundledoc` and the `--include="file1.sty, file2.sty"` so that bundledoc creates a new and shareable file that includes the important `.sty` files in it via the `filecontents` environment.  This will (probably) be more portable across time, space, and different file directory structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185684/specify-path-to-sister-directory-in-a-style-file?noredirect=1#comment429321_185684), it should be like this:

`.tex` file in the mother directory:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{./testfolder/testpackage}
\begin{document}
Test
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

`.sty` file in daughter directory 1:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{./testfolder/testpackage}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{testfolder2/testpackage2}
\endinput
```

`.sty` file in daughter directory 2:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testfolder2/testpackage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\endinput
```

Comment: If you do this then the package can _only_ be called from the parent directory, the package could never be installed in the normal tree and found via the tex path as the `\usepackage` _name_ argument has to be literally `{./testfolder/testpackage}` to avoid a warning.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are you saying that the ``.sty`` file in directory 1 should have ``\usepackage{testpackage2}`` and the ``.sty`` file in directory 2 should have ``\ProvidesPackage{testpackage2}``? Please clarify.

Comment: well the .sty in directory1 should have `\RequirePackage{testpackage2}` (although `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage` are identical really, and the document should have `\usepackage{testpackage}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But keeping ``\ProvidesPackage{testfolder2/testpackage2}`` in the ``.sty`` file in directory 2 is still correct?